# Iterating over a loop and plot subplot for each iterations using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am very new to python and I am stuck at something.
Below is the piece of code which plots two lists against each other :

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(24, 16), dpi= 80)
for item in temperature:
  plt.plot(timestamp,item)
plt.legend(final_cities, loc = 'best')
plt.xlabel('Date Time Stamp')
plt.ylabel('Temperature in Kelvin')
plt.show()
```

timestamp and temperature lists looks like:

```py
temperature=[[301.68, 300.71, 299.44, 299.6, 299.95], [306.41, 305.51, 303.36, 301.83, 303.37, 307.39]]
```

```py
timestamp=['2020-09-22 15:00:00', '2020-09-22 18:00:00', '2020-09-22 21:00:00', '2020-09-23 00:00:00', '2020-09-23 03:00:00']
```

My code is plotting 2 graphs on top of each other. I want to print each plot as a subplot. How do I do it?
Note: Each subplot will belong to a different country whose details are stored in a different list.

Comment: See https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```py
# data
x_data = [some list]
y_data = [some list]

#  x * y should be >= len(x_data) (the amount of subplots)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(x, y)

# use a counter to get elements from your list you want to plot
c = 0
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        axs[i][j].plot(x_data[c], y_data[c])
        c += 1

    if c > len(x_data):
        break

plt.show()
```